# EF Core 7 : Contains method exception: could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I want to write a LINQ query for finding 10 courses with the most intersect tags with a specific course.

I wrote it but I get an exception. I don't want to use `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` because I don't want to execute the query to get all the courses before getting 10.

I don't want to use other ORMs.

The code:

```
var courses = await _dbContext.Courses
                              .AsNoTracking()
                              .Where(c => c.Id != request.Id)
                              .Select(c => new
                                      {
                                           Course = c,
                                           IntersectTagsCount = c.Tags.Sum(t => course.Tags.Contains(t) ? 1 : 0)
                                      })
                              .OrderByDescending(c => c.IntersectTagsCount)
                              .Take(10)
                              .ToListAsync();
```

The error I get is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 't => __course_Tags_1 .Contains(t) ? 1 : 0' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

The entity looks like this:

[image: Entity class picture]

Which is stored in the database like this:

[image: SQL Server database table picture]

Comment: So, linq to entities can't translate your code to sql expression, need to rewrite or execute raw sql query.

Comment: @hamaronooo How should I rewrite it to not use raw query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue will be trying to inject another entity or DTO into the query expression. (counrse.Tags)

Give this a try.

```
var tagIds = course.Tags.Select(t => t.Id).ToList();

var courses = await _dbContext.Courses
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => c.Id != request.Id)
    .Select(c => new
    {
       Course = c,
       IntersectTagsCount = c.Tags.Sum(t => tagIds.Contains(t.Id) ? 1 : 0)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.IntersectTagsCount)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

**Edit:** Ok, I missed that you're storing the tags as an array within the entity. Unfortunately you won't be able to translate a Array.Sum where that Tags property likely needs to go through a value converter down to a varchar to build a comma-delimited value to store in the DB.

My recommendation is that if you need to be able to query/consolidate courses by tags, that you normalize the table structure so that Tag references can be related across courses. Something like this would be a standard many-to-many relationship where we create a Tag table (TagId & TagName) then a CourseTags table (CourseId & TagId as a composite PK with FKs back to their respective tables)

THe entity structure changes slightly:

```
[Table("Courses")]
public class Course
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}

[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
}
```

EF can manage the CourseTags table completely behind the scenes. In the above example I just used the tag name/string as the ID/PK (I.e. "TestTagName1") as this option might be less hassle to re-factor to use. If there are expected to be a lot of tags, I would recommend using an identity integer for the ID as it will be easier on the indexing.

Now assuming your client code passes a filtered array of tag IDs to check as course.tags (array of strings) then EF can now build a query across related Tag rows through the CourseTags relationship:

```
var courses = await _dbContext.Courses
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => c.Id != request.Id)
    .Select(c => new
    {
       Course = c,
       IntersectTagsCount = c.Tags.Sum(t => course.Tags.Contains(t.Id) ? 1 : 0)
    })
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.IntersectTagsCount)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The difference is now that EF has a relational relationship between Courses and Tags, it can build queries around the Linq operations since it knows a Course will be associated to a set of Tag records rather than containing a single column with the tag values appended together.

An alternative option which may work with EF Core 7 would be to store the Tags as a JSON set of values within the Course as I believe EF Core does support querying against JSON data. Unfortunately this isn't something I have spent time tinkering with yet but it might be worth looking into if you decide you really prefer storing the tags in a field rather than a relational table.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work for me. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Curious, I'll give this a try to reproduce because that should be able to be translated down to SQL.

Comment: AH.. I missed that you are storing tags as an array of strings within the entity. Are you using a value converter to convert that array into a single string column in the DB? In this case, no it won't work. If Tags are going to be queried/compaired like this I would recommend breaking them out into their own related table with a many-to-many relationship with courses. I'll update my answer with an example.